# Possible to manage display of Profile2 profile fieldset on user registration

Tags: display-suite, users

Using profile2 module I have set my Student profile to "Show during user account registration". This shows the fields I have created for the profile2 Student profile in a fieldset inside the user registration form.
I am now struggling to gain any control over the display of my profile2 Student profile fields on the registration form.
It is possible to manage the display of a profile2 profile displayed on the user registration form through display suite or another method, or is the only option using hook_form_alter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a while since I used panels for this, but I'm quite sure you can use panels, and enable the panels page for the user/%user/edit page. Then create a new variant for this page and rearrange the elements through the content section as you would for a front-end panel. If you're not already using panels for other aspects of your site, you may want to try Display Suite, which I've never tried out. Choose the one that works best for your needs and stick with it to avoid module bloat.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am already using display suite, but it appears (from a little research see latest posts https://drupal.org/node/1823106) to fall short of supporting profile2 view modes/display settings. I haven't used panels and don't plan to so they won't be an option.
It would be great if I could create a new entity view mode which could then be applied to profile2 form when rendered inside the registration form. Perhaps a feature request. Until then, I have managed to achieve what I want with hook_form_alter. Thanks